# Can I call Django Manager Methods from AngularJS?

Tags: python, django, angularjs

Is it possible to call Django Manager Methods from AngularJS?

For example like this factory PUT method called in AngularJS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);
// Some APIs expect a PUT request in the format URL/object/ID
// Here we are creating an 'update' method
app.factory('Notes', ['$resource', function($resource) {
return $resource('/notes/:id', null,
    {
        'update': { method:'PUT' }
    });
}]);
// snipped ...
Notes.update({ id:$id }, note);
```

But for Django's `get_or_create` for example?

So instead of this in Django:

```
obj, created = MyObject.objects.get_or_create(**kwargs)
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
app.factory('Notes', ['$resource', function($resource) {
return $resource('/notes/:id', null,
    {
        'get_or_create': // some code here but do not know what??
    });
}]);
// snipped ...
Notes.get_or_update({ id:$id }, note);
```

I'd like to do this because I have written a good deal of custom Django Managers and would like to use AngularJS for the UI, but don't want to re-write them all if necessary.

Thanks

Comment: What are you using on the backend for your API? `django-rest-framework`?  Custom-built API endpoints? You will need to put the `get_or_create()` code there.

Comment: without knowing django, what is the specific issue in setting up the angular requests? Can modify client side requests just about any way you need.

Comment: @DanielRobinson, okay, I am going to do that then.  Thank you for your help.  You have helped me before!

Comment: @charlietfl I can re-write the logic in AngularJS, but the issue is that I've already written most of the logic and wired it together, so don't want to rebuild it if I don't have to. Thanks.

Comment: logic to do what? If this is strictly a django question then remove angular tag. Otherwise need a better explanation of the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that Angular is a client-side framework, and Django is server side. The *only* way they can communicate is via HTTP, which means that if you want Angular to call a Django manager method, you need to expose that via a URL connected to a view. As the comments say, one way to do that is via Django REST framework, but if that's overkill for your use case you can always write the views yourself.